# Heroku Autoscale with Node.js

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have seen many implementations in Ruby for dynamically scaling heroku dynos and workers such as [heroku-autoscale](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-autoscale). How about node.js? Is there any modules for managing heroku instances for node.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of anything that already exists, but you can always interrogate the logs to see how busy your application is at the current time.

However, be very very wary of auto-scaling as it is a very complex topic.  For instance, let's say you get busy, and your database is a bottleneck.  You see a slow site, and thus crank on more dynos to try and speed up the queue.  This creates more traffic on the database and thus compounds the issue, and costs you more money.

Only auto-scale if you can be 100% sure in every way that scaling that particular process will alleviate any problems you might be having.

Comment: agreed, I would look into something that give you easy quick feedback via notification on bottlenecks with your app, and allows you to adjust easily.